# How to save multilingual data using Node.js + Mongoose + MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save multilingual data in my database. In Django, I was using django-transmeta and I could save and access the multilingual data easily.

In Mongoose, how I should save the data, or which modules should I use to to this?

For example, I want to save the names of an item in 3 languages:

In db, should it be:

```
{
  name : {
        en : 'Car',
        tr : 'Araba',
        es : 'Coche'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right...

That is one way of doing it:

```
{
  _id
  name : {
        en : 'Car',
        tr : 'Araba',
        es : 'Coche'
  }
}
```

Another is:

```
{
   YourId:'1'
   locale: 'en',   
   name: 'Car'
}
{
   YourId:'1'
   locale: 'tr',   
   name: 'Araba'
}
{
   YourId:'1'
   locale: 'es',   
   name: 'Coche'
}
```

And in the 2nd example, its good to index 'YourId' & 'locale'